# Can a magento store with 1000 websites and daily automated product updates be made to work by using multiple mysql per website?

Tags: mysql, magento

The mysql performance of running the magento for this situation under one mysql installation is giving a headache.    I wonder if it is feasible to setup an individual mysql for each website so that updates to the catalog can occur concurrently across all websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure can be made working within a cluster and if you queue your updates and plan ahead for such. But it won't be cheap and i'll guess you 'll need a mysql instance for every 30 to 50 website. It's worth to observe mysql sharding for heavily used tables and ways to run all this inside RAM to dramatically pull down the resource usage needed.

and for such task you have to be living and breathing INNODB person

Comment: wont be cheap?    
mysql sharding?
what if I scale this down to 100 websites with 5 catalogs?
how can this all be run inside RAM?

Comment: What would be the plan of attack to accomplish this with 100 websites and 5 catalogs and 1000 daily product updates?

Comment: Best plan is to outsource the knowledge and start with dedicated magento cluster hosting (starts around $1000 per month i guess). You can find few providers from google. If you are eager to learn this yourself then I'd suggest to buy a few books on mysql sharding and running mysql instances in memory. This is not an easy task to become a sys manager with innodb specialization who knows how to scale mysql vertically and horizontally

Comment: How would the magento application be set up?
1 master application, which uses 5 different mysql databases for product catalogs, with a lookup in the app to change the data source read and write resources depeding on the website which the customer was using?

Comment: it really depends on your write/read ratio and fault redundancy and what are the bottlenecks. To start with this you need to make up a benchmark against what you are starting to compare your performance I'm not a sys manager or devop myself and can only lead to right direction not actually implement this as i have only read all the famous mysql and scalability books from amazon

Comment: Just wanted to note, Magento has both read/write adapters built in. getConnection('core_read'); and getConnection('core_write'); making it easy to replicate read db's for performance scaling.  You may want to also checkout: http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/

Comment: Sure it's easy to replicate databases, but all media files is another story and adds quite a lot of complexity to your infra . Whis it was  as easy as it is with mongodb and gridfs